# How to obtain the convex curve for weights vs loss in a neural network

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, gradient-descent

In most of the literature of Neural networks the 3D plot of weights, bias and the loss function is shown as below, 
[image]
When I tried I obtained a plot like this one 
[image]

Here are more details, Here is the glimpse of the dataset, there are 15,000 training examples, 
[image]

Here is the formula of the cost function used, 
[image]

[image]

[Here is the link to the ipython notebook](https://github.com/hackintoshrao/blog-posts/blob/6af0f249b74c759b60d65fdb529d066004d68ba1/Neural%20Nets/Building%20Neural%20Nets%20From%20Scratch/Part%202/code/gradient_descent_visualization.ipynb) with the code and visualization.

I want to obtain the curve similar to the one that's shown in the first image for demonstration purpose.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What makes you think it is *not* convex??

Comment: the notebook is completely broken, it is full or `NameErrors` etc. - if you expect people to look at your code, at least make sure it is runnable

Comment: @MattiLyra: The notebook form the link https://github.com/hackintoshrao/blog-posts/blob/ddadec8ed279965c349a71710c6d72421b1437e3/Neural%20Nets/Building%20Neural%20Nets%20From%20Scratch/Part%202/code/gradient_descent_visualization.ipynb seems to be working.

Comment: @desertnaut: The don't see any bumps in the curve, but I'm not able to obtain the complete convex graph like this one https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/35389/versions/1/screenshot.png . May be I need to extend the values in the y axis.

Comment: The definition of convexity has nothing to do with bumps. Your plot looks convex indeed.

Comment: @desertnaut: I've edited the question. This now is precisely what I'm looking forward for.

Comment: @MattiLyra: You were right, apologies for the mistake. I've updated the code and it should run well now. Can you try running it using the code here https://github.com/hackintoshrao/blog-posts/blob/6af0f249b74c759b60d65fdb529d066004d68ba1/Neural%20Nets/Building%20Neural%20Nets%20From%20Scratch/Part%202/code/gradient_descent_visualization.ipynb

Answer (score 2):

To obtain the convex curve, do the following:

Plot coefficient w (weights) in your x axis
Plot intercept b in your y axis
Plot the cross entropy in your z axis.

Define a range for w and b and calculate cross entropy for each couple w, b

Plot x,y,z values in 3D. It's done.

Comment: Here is the updated code https://github.com/hackintoshrao/blog-posts/blob/6af0f249b74c759b60d65fdb529d066004d68ba1/Neural%20Nets/Building%20Neural%20Nets%20From%20Scratch/Part%202/code/gradient_descent_visualization.ipynb